# How to remove/separate conjoint words from tweets

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining, corpus, social-media

I am mining Twitter data and one of the problems I come across while cleaning text is, being unable to remove/separate conjoint words that are usually hashtag data. Upon removing special characters and symbols like '#', I am left with phrases that make no sense. For instance:

1) Meaningless words:  I have words like: 'spillwayjfleck' , 'bowhunterva' etc, which make no sense and need to be removed from my Corpus. Is there any function in R which can do it?.

2) Conjoint words: I need a method to separate joint words like: 'flashfloodwarn' to: 
'flash', 'flood', 'warn', from my Corpus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can remove words with tm_map(corpus_train, removeWords, c("thewordsyouwannaremov"))

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983495/how-to-split-a-text-into-two-meaningful-words-in-r

Comment: @NicoCoallier that's very cumbersome. My text file is huge and my corpus has a million words that don't make sense. I can't manually enter each and every word. Is there a solution that compares the words in my Corpus to words from the dictionary and eliminates all the meaningless words?

Comment: @NicoCoallier thanks. I'll look it up.

Comment: @NicoCoallier that post gives me a direction. But, again, I will have to plug-in words and check for every possible split. Isn't there an alternative?

Comment: Can I see how your data looks ?

Comment: You can apply a function to a dataframe or a list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715380/extract-english-words-from-a-text-in-r

Comment: If you give me an example of your data I can make you a function to do what you want

Comment: @NicoCoallier I am mining disaster-event tweets. My data is based on tweets on the Oroville Dam Spillway.                                                                                                                   For instance: RT PaulRogersSJMN: How fast are #OrovilleDam operators trying to drain the lake? 748,000 gallons per second. At about 50 mph. That's an im…
#LahoreBlast #LEMONADE #OrovilleDam #VuraOnAMilli #Quantico #RAWVegas #stopprofiling #TheBachelor #ukpunday #VGPusuanSaAraneta Unbelievable how political the feed on #OrovilleDam is.

Comment: But how is it organise can you show me à head() or inspect()

Comment: @NicoCoallier here you go:                                                                    > head(orv_tweets,4)
    [1] "Understand where those #Flood waters came from:  #OrovilleDam #OrovilleSpillway\nSashaPezenik"
    [2] "This is how those drastic water levels are possible. #OrovilleDam bfwebster zerohedge"       
    [3] "#OrovilleDam overview  mincing words  HealthRanger  LouDobbs KellyannePolls BreitbartNews starsandstripes"      
    [4] "#OrovilleDam provides drinking water for about  25 million #Californians, and water for farmers, fish and wildlife CAWaterAlliance"

Comment: Do you want to remove all hashtags? or only the ones that have conjoined words?

Comment: @FredBoehm I wish to remove all hashtags. But, I need to separate the conjoined words into separate words.